# For ggplot2 legend key, add border that matches color of other aesthetics with not fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am doing a ggplot in which color, fill, shape and linetype aesthetics are used. I would like the legend keys to have no fill, but I would like the color of the legend key border to match the color for the other aesthetics in the legend. Everything in the plot below is as I want it to be except the border.

Please let me know how I can make the color of the border for each key match the color for the rest of the key (i.e. the border for A would be gray, B would be yellow, C would be blue and D would be green).

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create sample data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(var_a = rnorm(20), 
                  var_b = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 5)) %>%
  mutate(response = case_when(var_b == 'A' ~ var_a + 1,
                              var_b == 'B' ~ var_a * 2,
                              var_b == 'C' ~ var_a * .5,
                              var_b == 'D' ~ 1)) %>%
  mutate(response = response + rnorm(nrow(.), 0, 0.1))



# Map colors to values of var_b
custom_color <- c('A' = "#999999", 'B' = "#F0E442", 
                    'C' = "#56B4E9", 'D' = "#009E73")

# Create custom theme
my_theme <- theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        legend.key.width = unit(0.35, 'in'))

# Create list with theme and manual aesthetic assignment
my_theme_list <- list(my_theme, 
                      scale_color_manual(values = custom_color),
                      scale_fill_manual(values = custom_color))

# Plot
plot_1 <- dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = var_a, y = response, color = var_b, shape = var_b,
                   linetype = var_b, fill = var_b)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  my_theme_list +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA))) +
  # Here's the part that's not working
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = custom_color))

plot_1

# Somehow plot(ggeffect()) is able to color the legend key boxes, but I can't
#  figure out how it does it
library(ggeffect)
mod <- lm(response ~ var_a * var_b, data = dat)

plot(ggeffect(mod, c('var_a', 'var_b'))
```

Comment: i think what you're trying to achieve does not bring any extra information to the plot. the colours are represented as a line inside each legend box already. since colour and fill assume same colour patterns, the legend completely explains the plot. in terms of aesthetics your plot is also looking good (in my opinion)..

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga - I agree, but I am working on a similar plot for someone who does not want to use color in case a plot is copied in black and white.  It seems a dated policy, but I'm trying to provide what they requested.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that via `theme` you can draw a border around the keys, however to the best of my knowledge you can not have different border colors for the keys. One way to to achieve your desired result is by means of a custom key glyph which combines the default point glyph (`draw_key_point`) for `geom_point` with a rectangle glyph (`draw_key_rect`):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create sample data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(var_a = rnorm(20), 
                  var_b = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 5)) %>%
  mutate(response = case_when(var_b == 'A' ~ var_a + 1,
                              var_b == 'B' ~ var_a * 2,
                              var_b == 'C' ~ var_a * .5,
                              var_b == 'D' ~ 1)) %>%
  mutate(response = response + rnorm(nrow(.), 0, 0.1))



# Map colors to values of var_b
custom_color <- c('A' = "#999999", 'B' = "#F0E442", 
                  'C' = "#56B4E9", 'D' = "#009E73")

# Create custom theme
my_theme <- theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        legend.key.width = unit(0.35, 'in'))

# Create list with theme and manual aesthetic assignment
my_theme_list <- list(my_theme, 
                      scale_color_manual(values = custom_color),
                      scale_fill_manual(values = custom_color))

# Plot
draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  grid::grobTree(
    grid::rectGrob(gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour, 
      fill = data$fill, 
      lty = data$linetype)),
    grid::pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5, 
                     pch = data$shape,
                     gp = grid::gpar(
                       col = data$colour,
                       fill = data$fill,
                       fontsize = data$size * .pt))
  )
}

plot_1 <- dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = var_a, y = response, color = var_b, shape = var_b,
                             linetype = var_b, fill = var_b)) +
  geom_point(key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  my_theme_list +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))

plot_1
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the less hacky of the two solutions Stefan - I would use something like this if I was making a package. It's more succinct than I thought too. Shame I can only upvote once!

Comment: Allan and Stefan, thanks very much for both of your answers. They both work very well. I agree that Stefan's is more succinct, and I'm starting to figure out how it works. Almost everything in it is new to me, and it's very impressive. If anyone is interested, I've added code for ggeffect() to the code in my question.  Somehow it is able to color boxes as I want it to, but I haven't been able to figure out how it does it.

Answer (score 2):

As Stefan points out, this parameter is not vectorized.

The alternative to writing an extension is to render the plot and modify the grobs from which it is constructed:

```r
plot_2 <- ggplotGrob(plot_1)
legend <- which(plot_2$layout$name == "guide-box")
guides <-  which(plot_2$grobs[[legend]]$layout$name == "guides")
bgs    <- grep("bg", plot_2$grobs[[legend]]$grobs[[guides]]$layout$name)
box_grobs <- plot_2$grobs[[legend]]$grobs[[guides]]$grobs[bgs]

plot_2$grobs[[legend]]$grobs[[guides]]$grobs[bgs] <- mapply( function(x, y) {
  x$gp$col <- y; x
  }, box_grobs, custom_color, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

grid::grid.draw(plot_2)
```

[image]